# MongoDB "'$' by itself is not a valid FieldPath" when using Aggregation Pipeplines on an Update operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to execute an update operation using aggregation pipelines on a Node.js project with mongoose. Here's my code:

```js
// Model schema
let productSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    currency: { type: String, required: false },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, required: false },
    tags: [String],
});

// Update operation
module.exports.update = async (product) => {

    await productModel.findByIdAndUpdate(product._id,
        [{
            $set:
            {
                name: product.name,
                description: product.description,
                currency: product.currency,
                price: product.price,
                updatedAt: '$$NOW',
                tags: { $concatArrays: [ '$tags', product.newTags  ] }
            }
        }],
        { 
            runValidators: true
        });
}
```

When I execut the update function, I get the following error:

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "'$' by itself is not a valid FieldPath",
    "code": 16872,
    "codeName": "Location16872",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

> Node.js version: 12.13
>
> MongoDB version: 4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the value I was receveing in `product.currency` was "$" and that was what was causing the error. To fix it I had to use the `$literal` operator to wrap up `product.currency`, like so:

```js
module.exports.update = async (product) => {

    await productModel.findByIdAndUpdate(product._id,
        [{
            $set:
            {
                name: product.name,
                description: product.description,
                currency: { $literal: product.currency }, // <--- here!
                price: product.price,
                updatedAt: '$$NOW',
                tags: { $concatArrays: [ '$tags', product.newTags  ] }
            }
        }],
        { 
            runValidators: true
        });
}
```

According to the [official MongoDB docs on `$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/):

> Returns a value without parsing. Use for values that the aggregation pipeline may interpret as an expression.